# TypeError: Failed to fetch from API server React JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

So I get TypeError: Failed to fetch on React JS code. It says the error is on index.js line 5 and 15, My API server is up and running so i don't think its the API server. Whenever i click on submit, I get empty data undefined which should have been an array and typeerror. It was supposed to pass me an array when I clicked on submit in console

index.js

```
import {API} from "../../backend"
import {cartEmpty} from "../../core/helper/cartHelper"

export const signup = user => {
    return fetch(`${API}users/`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            Accecpt : "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(user)
    })
    .then((response) => {
        return response.json()
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}

export const signin = user => {
    const formData = new FormData()
    for (const name in user) {
        formData.append(name, user[name])
    }
    return fetch(`${API}user/login`, {
        method: "POST",
        body: FormData
    })
    .then(response => {
        return response.json()
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}

export const authenticate = (data, next) => {
    if (typeof window !== undefined) {
        localStorage.setItem("jwt", JSON.stringify(data))
        next()
    }
}

export const isAuthenticated = () => {
    if (typeof window == undefined) {
        return false
    }
    if (localStorage.getItem("jwt")) {
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("jwt"))
    } else {
        return false
    }
}

export const signout = next => {
    const userId = isAuthenticated() && isAuthenticated().user.id
    if (typeof window !== undefined) {
        localStorage.removeItem("jwt")
        cartEmpty(() => {})
        //next()
        return fetch(`${API}user/logout/${userId}`, {
            method: "GET"
        })
        .then(response => {
            console.log("Signout success")
            next()
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }

}
```

Signup.js

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import Base from '../core/Base'
import {Link} from "react-router-dom"
import { signup } from '../auth/helper'
import { stringify } from 'query-string'

const Signup = () => {
    const [values, setValues] = useState({
        name: "",
        email: "",
        pasword: "",
        error: "",
        success: false
    })
    const {name, email, password, error, success} = values
    const handleChange = name => event => {
        setValues({...values, error: false, [name]: event.target.value})
    }
    const onSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        setValues({...values, error: false})
        signup({name, email, password})
        .then(data => {
            console.log("DATA", data)
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
    const signUpForm = () => {
        return (
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-6 offset-sm-3 text-left">
                    <form>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label className="text-light">Name</label>
                            <input onChange={handleChange("name")} value={name} className="form-control" type="text"></input>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label className="text-light">Email</label>
                            <input onChange={handleChange("email")} value={email} className="form-control" type="email"></input>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label className="text-light">Password</label>
                            <input onChange={handleChange("password")} value={password} className="form-control" type="password"></input>
                        </div>
                        <button onClick={onSubmit} className="btn btn-success btn-block">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
    return (
        <Base title="Sign up Page" description="A signup">
            {signUpForm()}
            <p className="text-white text-center">{JSON.stringify(values)}</p>
            
        </Base>
    )
}
export default Signup
```

Comment: What is `API` that you import from "../../backend"? Is it the URL to your backend server, I assume, right? Like "http://localhost:3000/"

Comment: Yeah, I'm using React for frontend and django for backend, they are connected via API

Comment: You have a typo in Accecpt : "application/json",.. could be the issue for communication with your API